# If $\mathbb{Z}_m^*$ is cyclic, and $\mathbb{Z}_m^*=\langle\overline{g}\rangle$, is $\overline{g}$ a primitive root?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Based on the definition I have of a primitive root:

> If $(a,m)=1$ and $a$ has order $\varphi(m)$ modulo $m$, then $a$ is called a primitive root modulo $m$.

it would appear that all the generators of the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_m^*$ (when $m$ is such that it **is** cyclic) have this property. For example, $\mathbb{Z}_9^*$ has generators $\overline{2}$ and $\overline{5}$... both of which have order $\varphi(9)=6$.

Is this a coincidence, or did I stumble on something?

Comment: "The cyclic group $\mathbb Z_m^*$" is a misnomer. Only some such groups are cyclic. For example $Z_{15}^*$ is not cyclic - ever element has order at most $4$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I meant to imply when it **is** cyclic; as in, when $m=1,2,4$, or is of the form $p^{\alpha}$ or $2p^{\alpha}$ where $p$ is an odd prime.

Answer (score 1):

That's the definition! "Primitive root mod $m$" means a number $k$ such that every number relatively prime to $m$ is congruent to a power of $k$ mod $m$, or in other words $k \pmod{m}$ is a generator for the multiplicative group of units mod $m$. As you can see, if a primitive root exists then the group of units is necessarily cyclic. But beware: for some $n$, there are no primitive roots.